# Does Java have a multiset data structure like the one in C++ STL?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need a data structure which works like the STL multiset but the TreeSet in Java doesn't allow duplicate elements. Is there any built-in data structure in Java which is equivalent to multiset?

Comment: `Map<E, Integer>`  where the integer is the count?

Comment: @delnan Set<List<E>> is a way around but the operations are not that clean as the mutliset.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Actually I have a bounch of objects which is ordered by their keys.

Comment: That would normally be a TreeMap for sorted keys and a collection for the duplicates.

Comment: com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset is what you want, i believe

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no Multiset in the standard Java libraries. You should use the Google Guava framework which contains Multiset classes.
[See](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset)

Comment: Google's multiset is not like C++ multiset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088057/does-treemultiset-only-holds-the-count-of-repeats-for-each-key

Comment: com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset is what you want, i believe

Comment: The `multiset` will use a internal counter to omit duplicate values, this is not equal to c++'s `std::multiset`

Answer (score 45):

Using `Map<E, Integer>` where Integer is the count is a good replacement for Multiset, and it does not need any third party library as well.

**Update:** If you really want to store the object twice, use a List with a Map like `Map<E, List<E>>`.

Comment: In this case, the complexity of getting the size of the set will be O(n)

Answer (score 8):

[Algorithms 4th edition](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/) has a [`Bag`](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Bag.java.html) implementation that's available on the book's web site.  You can view the [javadoc](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/javadoc/Bag.html) online as well.

> The Bag class represents a bag (or multiset) of generic items. It supports insertion and iterating over the items in arbitrary order.

You'll probably just want to have a look at the source code if `Bag` is all you need, but there are a lot of other interesting things in `algs4.jar`, so it's worth a look.

Comment: Actually it is not what I am looking for because it uses linked list as the underlying data structure which is O(n) for finding.

Comment: @outlaw Yes, that one is.  If you do want to write your own, there are a few other data structures in those examples that you could look at that use a backing array instead of a linked list.  See [`ResizingArrayQueue`](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/ResizingArrayQueue.java.html) for one example.

Comment: Note that this code is likely GPL licensed per https://web.archive.org/web/20171202160133/https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/faq/.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) has [`Bag`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html) and [`SortedBag`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/SortedBag.html) interfaces.  It sounds like [`TreeBag`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/TreeBag.html) might meet your needs, but there are plenty of implementations to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PriorityQueue The elements are sorted in their natural order, or if you provide one, by comparator, and duplicates are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
TreeSet<Integer> multiset = new TreeSet<>((i, j) -> i < j ? 1 : -1);
```

Make a set multiset just by making 1 != 1!

Comment: You will not be able to delete from such set

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.8, Map allows you to do this:

```
  map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<V>()).add(v);
```

Each value is added into a Set, which is created on demand.

You may need to change remove() too.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented using TreeMap

```
 public static class multiset{
    public TreeMap<Integer,Integer> map;
    public int size=0;
    public multiset(){
        map=new TreeMap<>();
    }
    public multiset(int[] a){
        map=new TreeMap<>();
        size=a.length;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            map.put(a[i], map.getOrDefault(a[i], 0)+1);
        }
    }
    void add(int a){
        size++;
        map.put(a, map.getOrDefault(a, 0)+1);
    }
    void remove(int a){
        size--;
        int val=map.get(a);
        map.put(a, val-1);
        if(val==1)map.remove(a);
    }
    void removeAll(int a){
        if(map.containsKey(a))
        {
            size-=map.get(a);
            map.remove(a);
        }
    }
    int ceiling(int a){
        if (map.ceilingKey(a) != null) {
            int find = map.ceilingKey(a);
            return find;
        }else return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    int floor(int a){
        if (map.floorKey(a) != null) {
            int find = map.floorKey(a);
            return find;
        }else return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    int lower(int a){
        if (map.lowerKey(a) != null) {
            int find = map.lowerKey(a);
            return find;
        }else return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    int higher(int a){
        if (map.higherKey(a) != null) {
            int find = map.higherKey(a);
            return find;
        }else return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    int first(){
        return map.firstKey();
    }
    int last(){
        return map.lastKey();
    }
    boolean contains(int a){
        if(map.containsKey(a))return true;
        return false;
    }
    int size(){
        return size;
    }
    void clear(){
        map.clear();
    }
    int poll(){
        if(map.size()==0){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        size--;
        int first=map.firstKey();
        if(map.get(first)==1){
            map.pollFirstEntry();
        }else map.put(first, map.get(first)-1);
        return first;
    }
    int polllast(){
        if(map.size()==0){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        size--;
        int last=map.lastKey();
        if(map.get(last)==1){
            map.pollLastEntry();
        }else map.put(last, map.get(last)-1);
        return last;
    }
}
```