# Does TreeMultiset only holds the count of repeats for each key?

Tags: java, guava

I tried the following code with TreeMultiset. Seems like the "*Twin" entries are discarded and the number of repeats are stored in TreeMultiset. I suppose this is a feature and not a bug. Is there an object that stores each object rather than a key and a count of  repeats?

```
public class Guava {

    public static class Obj implements Comparable<Obj> {

        String name;
        int age;

        public Obj(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s@%d", name, age);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Obj o) {
            return Integer.compare(age, o.age);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMultiset<Obj> tree = TreeMultiset.create();
        tree.add(new Obj("Ajo", 37));
        tree.add(new Obj("AjoTwin", 37));
        tree.add(new Obj("Ari", 31));
        tree.add(new Obj("AriTwin", 31));
        tree.add(new Obj("Fly", 1));
        System.out.println(tree.size());
        for (Obj obj : tree) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a collection that maintains multiple elements that are `equal` you should not be using a `Set`. You might want to think about using a normal implementation of `equals` and use `Equivalence` for the same age behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we know for sure is:

> [MultiSet-Docu](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset_Is_Not_A_Map): Note that `Multiset<E>` is not a `Map<E, Integer>`, though that might be part of a `Multiset` implementation. `Multiset` is a true `Collection` type, and satisfies all of the associated contractual obligations.

That means that `MultiSet` is more or less a `Set` (it does not implement `Set`) that also counts. And a `Set` contains no duplicate elements.

A true `Set` also keeps just the first element you inserted and discard any further equal ones.

> [`Set#add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29): If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

Since `TreeMultiSet` uses `compareTo` instead of `equals` you'll have to end up with the result you get.

Note: You should implement `.equals` analog to `.compareTo`:

> [TreeMultiSet-Docu](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html): The comparison must be consistent with equals as explained by the Comparable class specification. Otherwise, the resulting multiset will violate the Collection contract, which is specified in terms of Object.equals(java.lang.Object).

---

If you want something that can store multiple elements try a `(List)MultiMap`. That's basically a `Map<Key, List<Value>>` that automatically adds elements to the list if they have the same key.

Answer (score 3):

If you are saying that two objects are equal, but not really equals this is bound to lead to confusion.  In this case I would use a List of List of Obj.

For your example you could use a TreeSet if you changed the compare, but I imagine you want to be able to look up by the integer.  In this case you can use a TreeMultimap.